# Eclipse Plugin Development: Make plugin dependent on CDT-plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-kepler

I am writing a plugin which I want to use the CDT-plugin (since I don't want to implement my own brand new C/C++ editor).

Questions:

- How is it possible to set the dependencies of my plugin to this particular editor
- How can I set this editor as a nature of this project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fro your first question, simply add the CDT plugins to your *Required plug-ins* of your project. [Details here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/editors/manifest_editor/dependencies.htm).

Editors and natures are different things, you cannot set an *"editor as a nature"*. Probably what you're searching for is the C++ nature you want to set for a project programmatically. Simply search the nature's ID in the `.project` file of a C++ project, then you can start looking into the details.

Comment: Hi @rlegendi ! Let's say I want to host my plugin later on somewhere, will Eclipse recognize the dependencies and e.g. hint the downloading user that my plugin requires the CDT-plugin? Okay, I assume that I can simply set the C/C++ nature provided by CDT-plugin and then modify it to my needs. Is that correct?

Comment: Yep, that's the way to do it :-) Though you'll need a feature and an update site for that too (easy to start them but you can spend ages figuring out configuration issues). Good luck with it!

Comment: Alright, this brought me on the right track but I seems that I can not simply extend the cnature (nature of CDT). Since I need to implement my own builder I am not quiet sure what CDT provides to make this simpler and what it does not provide. I want to use CDT and compile with SDCC. Do you have any advice for me? ^^ But thank you anyway - it truly put me on the right track... a very long track as it seems ^^

Comment: You should get the source of CDT in the first place, then I found  FAQ that may help you get started: http://cdt-devel-faq.wikidot.com/ Hope that helps.

Comment: Alright, thank you that looks helpful. I already found a SDCC Plugin for Eclipse http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-sdcc/ which I'm afraid does not fullfill my needs completely - but anyway - I'm going to extend this plugin. Thanks for your help!